# EclipseLink-4021 - Unable to acquire a connection from driver

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jpa, servlets, eclipselink

I often get an exception **EclipseLink-4021 "Unable to acquire a connection from driver [null], user [null] and URL [null]"** when my application start.

This mean that Eclipselink doesn't find persistence.xml defined to connect to MySQL.
My persistence.xml is in folder /WEB-INF/classes, I think this is the standard place.

When I start tomcat again and again it finally work.
When anything run well, I get this log.

```
[EL Info]: 2016-07-01 11:22:55.268--ServerSession(975412652)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5
[EL Info]: connection: 2016-07-01 11:22:56.794--ServerSession(975412652)--/file:/D:/Workspace_Eclipse/xxxWebapp/target/classes/_db1 login successful
```

I think this could come from my WebApp's architecture but I don't understand what is going wrong.

My WebApp is develop with Java 8, ZK 8, EclipseLink 2.6.3, MySQL 5.7.10

At the init a HttpServlet (GlobalEnvProperties.java) is called to prepare things like connections to other database and quartz scheduler.

web.xml complete content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
    <description>app</description>
    <display-name>Webapp</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>ZK loader for ZUML pages</description>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>update-uri</param-name>
            <param-value>/zkau</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.zul</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.zhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <description>The asynchronous update engine for ZK</description>
        <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/zkau/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <description>ZK listener for session cleanup</description>
        <listener-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>14400</session-timeout>
    </session-config>   
    <servlet>
        <description>Gestion des environnements</description>
        <servlet-name>GlobalEnvProperties</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.company.app.webapp.common.GlobalEnvProperties</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>    
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>doc</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-word</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>gif</extension>
        <mime-type>image/gif</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>htm</extension>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>html</extension>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jpeg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jpg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>js</extension>
        <mime-type>text/javascript</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>pdf</extension>
        <mime-type>application/pdf</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>png</extension>
        <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>txt</extension>
        <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xls</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-excel</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xml</extension>
        <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>zhtml</extension>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>zul</extension>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>auth.zul</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

In the init void of the servlet GlobalEnvProperties, I get EntityManager with **Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("db1")**

```
public void init() throws ServletException {
        bddFactories = new HashMap<String, EntityManagerFactory>();
        entityManagers = new HashMap<String, EntityManager>();
        //global properties
        configProp = new Properties();
        InputStream ficProperties = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/app.properties");
        try {
            configProp.load(new InputStreamReader(ficProperties, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            CustomLogger.info("Unable to open properties file");
            CustomLogger.tracerErreurFatale(e);
        }

        /*
         * BDD connection
         */    
        // Base db1
        try {
            final int sleepChargementPersitence = 10000;
            Thread.sleep(sleepChargementPersitence);
            bddFactories.put("db1", Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("db1"));
        } catch (javax.persistence.PersistenceException | DatabaseException e) {
            CustomLogger.info("Unable to connect db1");
            CustomLogger.tracerErreurFatale(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            CustomLogger.info("Sleep failed");
        }

        OtherConnectionsLoad();

        //scheduler 
  try {
            CustomLogger.debug("Scheduler start");
            DailyTreatmentScheduler.main(null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My persistence.xml content :

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="db1">
        <class>com.company.app.model.Action</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>                                              
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*******" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://server:3306/db1?useSSL=false" />            
            <property name="eclipselink.deploy-on-startup" value="true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.initialSize" value="2" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.maxActive" value="10" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.logging.level" value="INFO" />
            <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.refresh" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I hope someone could explain where I'm wrong.
Thanks for those who will try to understand my problem.

Comment: Your code is trying to access persistence unit 'db1' while the persistence.xml shows 'nova'.  The error you show isn't that it can't find a persistence unit, it is that the persistence unit doesn't have valid URL and other connection properties.

Comment: I've changed database name while I was writing my question in order to respect confidentiality policy of my company. I've forgot to change the one you've seen. The same name is used everywhere in my code. sorry for this omission.

Comment: My statement on the error still stands.  Check that it isn't loading some other persistence.xml file with incomplete or improper properties being passed in.  You can turn on logging to finest to help track down what might be going on when it loads.

Comment: I've try to found how to increase log level but the only thing I know is the property <property name="javax.persistence.logging.level" value="FINEST" /> in persistence.xml. I can't use this way because when my problem occurs eclipselink don't load persistence.xml

Comment: Your error states it does load a persistence.xml, but cannot find the driver connection properties.  The problem is your application must be loading the wrong persistence.xml file that has the same db1 persistence unit name. The file should be in the META-INF directory at the base of the persistence unit, so in the classes directory if it is an expanded structure.  You will need to find any other persistence.xml files that might be interfering with the loading of your application.

Comment: Hi Chris,Thanks for your help. You're right. I had a mistake in my POM. In consequence, I got to copies of persistence.xml, one in target/nova/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/, the other in target/nova/WEB-INF/. After correction, the problem is solved. Please answer to the question so I can vote for you.